# How can i get image from binaryfield in django-rest

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model with a binaryfield.The data in myRow is in base64 format.Now I want to get image from this base64 data stored in database.Can somebody help....

```
class myTable(models.Model):
     myRow = models.BinaryField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: please dont tell me to use ImageField in django....my specific requirement is different...

Comment: Decode the base64 encoded string and write it to a file. Python has a built-in base64 module.

Comment: You can add the file to response body.

Comment: If you simply want to display the image in browser, you don't even need to decode the string on server. You can display base64 string in browser using [Data URI Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way and get the image.

```
myRowimage = request.FILES['myRow'].file.read()
```

But I will recommend you to use **Django's builtin** [ImageField](http://image_file%20=%20request.FILES['image_file'].file.read()).

Comment: It is not working...can you tell me how to convert base64 to image in django......?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did (adding image in admin).
[How to upload files into BinaryField using FileField widget in Django Admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692520/how-to-upload-files-into-binaryfield-using-filefield-widget-in-django-admin/70393299#70393299)

You have to set up an input file widget and saving the data in binary.
Than you load and decode it back.