# How to Download BinaryField in django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am working on a legacy system, where an institution's logo field is declared as a BinaryField, I was able to upload the file using the file input widget, how can I edit the registry to be able to download the file? As with FileField.
I use this for upload file [add_file_upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58529099/adding-file-upload-widget-for-binaryfield-to-django-admin)

Comment: since there's no file (it's a binary blob saved to your database) there isn't a file to download, unless you create a specific view for it that returns a downloadable file. But if you just want to render it in HTML, why not use `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ obj.logo }}">`?

Comment: I think the right way is to render it really, I never overwrote django template, any tips?

Comment: Or just return ```<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ obj.logo }}">``` in my admin?